# Run Command Id in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to know the command ID for the Run-> run(ctrl + F11). I tried searching for in the Plug-in search

org.eclipse.ui.bindings
org.eclipse.ui.actionSets

but I cant find the command id for ctrl+F11 (w/c is Run).

org.eclipse.ui.actionSets - org.eclipse.ajdt.ui
org.eclipse.ui.actionSets - org.eclipse.ant.ui

I am creating a plugin. In which Run is in the menu of the plugin. And i need to trigger the Run of the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: if you are just interested in trigger `Run` command in Eclipse. You may take look at this : https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control. Further, with this plugin and EASE script project, you can archive more functional things by just script.

Answer (score 0):

This is defined using the old style action set:

```xml
 <action
      id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.RunLast"
       hoverIcon="$nl$/icons/full/elcl16/runlast_co.png"
       class="org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.RunLastAction"
       definitionId="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunLast"
       disabledIcon="$nl$/icons/full/dlcl16/runlast_co.png"
       icon="$nl$/icons/full/elcl16/runlast_co.png"
       helpContextId="run_last_action_context"
       label="%ContextLaunchingRunMenu.name"
       menubarPath="org.eclipse.ui.run/relaunchGroup">
 </action>
```

So the command id is `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunLast`

Comment: hey is it possible to call the commandid in the execute method? (in the handler). its like its just part of the menu. it has to do other actions other than run.